# Painting onto textures - cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, texture-painting

I'm on the road to modeling and texturing a old castle ruin near from home, I scanned the ruins to have some blueprints and realistic texture patterns. The project is modeling the missing parts of the castle according to archaeological and historical research. 
I finished modeling and wood texturing, now I'm doing the stone and wall texturing and it's not so easy.
My walls look too flat and too perfect.
Like this : [image: https://static.turbosquid.com/Preview/2015/07/01__15_19_09/DropBox1.jpg5eb77065-e582-4e26-b5a5-cb0c24584200Original.jpg]

What I'm looking for is something like this: 
[image: https://scontent-cdt1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t31.0-8/26678036_10154856331376548_8505651681109732632_o.jpg?_nc_cat=101&_nc_ht=scontent-cdt1-1.xx&oh=951814aca7a176960673a9fc09a25c7c&oe=5CE648AF]
As you can see on the foreground wall, there are some water infiltrations on the bottom, some of the bricks looks broken, the plaster touchs ... everything looks irregular, its realistic. 
Or on this one [image: https://cdnb.artstation.com/p/assets/images/images/013/447/289/large/jessyca-lemire-bertrand-s21-003.jpg?1539642248]

It's what I want to do on my wall and I want to know the best way.

Is there any solution to mix a repetitive texture pattern (e.g. the wall texture) and painted parts in multiple layers?

If it's no, what is the best way to have these kind of effects?

Comment: Can you show some screen shots that explain what your mesh wireframe looks like, how you are using the textures so far and how the UV map looks? I would suggest some things but I can't tell from the first picture how you have the texture mapped and if you are just tiling an image. I would suggest looking at using more than one UV mapping so that you can tile a texture and also have another image texture for each wall that can add effects like grunge and broken area. If no one else can, I will make an example this evening.

Comment: Hi Craig and Thanks
Actually, my wall are pretty simple, just a shape, a material and a normal map, but, when it will be ok with this problem, it will have a displacement map and probably some additionnal node ( noise, glossy parts, ... ) to improve all of this. 
My Unwraping method is the patern is not repeated on Z axis but it is on X and Y as you can see on this pic. 
https://ibb.co/b6b1f9p
i've no particular method because i'm looking for the best one, the only thing I want is to make those effects in blender not in postprod


Thanks again

Comment: Also, on your actual model maybe experiment with adding a bevel modifier to the walls so that you don't have such a sharp edge.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will explain how I use stencil images to make use of tiled textures. I paint the stencils using different brush and brush mask textures.
We want to set up our uv mapping to make the best use of the tiled texture to make it spread across our object.
[image]
So we need to use the UV layer and rename it to tiled, and we want to arrange the uvs so that we get a nice texel size - stretching outside the constrains of the uv window is fine, as the texture just repeats past it and scaling way past just means we can see the texture decreasing in relationship to the actual face size.
[image]
We now want a second uv mapping layer for our stencil , and we will use Smart UV Project here so that we will be able to paint on a stencil over the whole object.
[image]
We will set up an initial node tree that mixes two tiled brick textures, even thoguh they aren't exactly the same scale we can use the same UV map to control how it lines up. We only see one brick texture without having painted the first stencil yet.
[image]
With the Stencil for the bricks in place, we can paint into small patches with a hard curve brush with white and reveal the second brick - I like to try to keep the paint inside the brick shapes from the first image, making it easier to blend them together.
[image]
We repeat the process, adding a stencil and a tiled image for the plaster.
[image]
I use a combination of procedural textures here, one set to 3d mapping on the brush at a small scale and another set to tiled at a large scale on the brush mask texture - procedurals are your friend here, allowing you to get interesting effects rather quickly.
[image]
We then can add another stencil and a tiled moss image texture.
[image]
If you make a new texbrush, you can set it to use jitter and wide spacing on the stroke, and set the radius to use pressure, painting in the moss where you want it.
[image]

I hope that helps - once you paint your object the way you want, you can use the same method to paint other objects in the scene. How you apply it is up to you, and you can use this same technique applied to mixing shader node groups with the matching tiled normal maps, and you can go so far as to also paint in dirt and cracks on another image multiplied - if you do that, start that one with a white image and paint with black.

Good luck!

Comment: Hi Craig and really thank you for your long and complete answer. 

It seams to work until the step 5 ( painting mask ). when i'm on material view mode its ok, i can see the mix with my drawing as limit ( my second image is my normal image, so its easily viewable ) but not in rendered and on scene render ... 
If i disconnect the masking image and move " fac " cursor, i can see both, so it's just a mask problem. 

I created a black bg picture and then white paint on it in paint mode. and i can see the patern in material mode. 

What I did wrong ? 

Thanks again !!! great trick !

Comment: Are you using 2.79b or 2.80?

Comment: If using Cycles in 2.79b, you may need to save the image paint as you go before seeing it in Render view - this is not an issue in 2.80.

Comment: Hi Again, 
Yes my mistake i didn't save my painted image ... ! 
Really thanks again ;)