# Painting parts of one texture onto another texture?

Tags: texturing, texture-painting

I have been looking around but Im still a little unsure about how to go about solving the following problem.

I have a wall with a brick texture on it but at the minute it looks too clean and perfect. I have a second texture (a sheet of moss) and I want to paint parts of this texture onto certain areas of the brick texture (perhaps in between the bricks). I have tried with the paint brush using things like the mask but still have had no luck.

Any ideas how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try the stencil mapping in the Texture tab of the brush?

Comment: I would use a “mix RGB“ node in the shaders editor, and then use a noise texture to control its factor.

Comment: Maybe the answer I gave here could help https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/131769/painting-onto-textures-cycles/131884#131884